# Cropping video with FFmpeg increases the tbn value too much

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, hardware, crop

Here is the information of original video:

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-04-05 03:00:09
  Duration: 00:01:50.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8131 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 7995 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 44.49 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
```

Then I used this `ffmpeg` command to crop video:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf "crop=480:480:0:0" -b:v 2048k -preset ultrafast cropped.mp4
```

Here is the information of cropped video:

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.101
  Duration: 00:01:50.16, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 1078 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1282x716 [SAR 1:1 DAR 641:358], 1002 kb/s, 44.49 fps, 44.49 tbr, 220455000.00 tbn, 88.98 tbc (default)
```

The default video player of my phone cannot play this video. If I use **MX Player** I have to change the decoder to **Software decoder** (instead of **Hardware**) to open it.

I noticed that the **tbn** value was increased after reencoding. The old value is **90k**. The new value is **220455k**. Maybe it is the reason why the default video player doesn't work.

Question: why is the `tbn` value so big? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `tbn` for a MOV/MP4 file by using `video_track_timescale`:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf "crop=480:480:0:0" -b:v 2048k -preset ultrafast \
       -video_track_timescale 90000 cropped.mp4
```

(You may also need to try expressly setting an output framerate `-r 45`)

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect!